# Rails + tinymce-rails weird error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce

I'm using tinymce-rails for a form .... until last night everything worked fine ... this morning when I came in and tried to run the form I get this error

`undefined local variable or method 'tinymce'`

the weird part is if I save the controller with :w in vim without making any changes to the file ... the error disappears and everything works ... any ideas ?

Comment: that's pretty wierd. did the system cahnge anyhow? any updates of system components?

Comment: nope ... nothing , I fixed it by adding   helper(TinyMCE::Rails::Helper) in the controller
but I still have no idea what happened ...

Comment: Hi , I also getting the same error, and bundle installs tinymce-rails (3.4.8, 3.4.7) in Gem file I gave gem 'tinymce-rails'.
I can't even call <%= tinymce_assets %> at that time i'm getting an error 'undefined local variable or method `tinymce_assets''

Comment: does adding helper(TinyMCE::Rails::Helper) in the controller work ?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried to add that also but getting error like 'uninitialized constant TinyMCE::Rails', I've only one controller called a common controller then I use models to edit and I'm using jruby and rails 3.1

Comment: this is how I put in view file.
<textarea name="<%='article_body' %>"  id="<%='article_body' %>" class ="<%='tinymce' %>" style="width:120%; height:400px;" ><%= @content_data['article_body'] %></textarea>
I tried this also

<%= text_area_tag :article_body, "", :class => "tinymce", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>
In both cases the tiny_mce controls not displaying only text area,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding helper(TinyMCE::Rails::Helper) in the controller but I still have no idea what happened

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue (rails 3.1), may be because i was using the advance theme.
then added this in application.js

//= require tinymce
//= require tinymce-jquery

and the theme folder from tinymce to assets folder

Worked for me... not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
gem update tinymce-rails
bundle update
```

And you should get your gem updated